# Jquery How to start function on page load and wait 5 sec?

Tags: jquery

I need the function snap to automatically start 5 seconds after loading the page.

How i do this?

The full code sould take a snapshot from a video file in principle

```
<span id="snap" onclick="snap()" style="color:red">Take Screenshot</span>

<script>
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var w, h, ratio;

video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(){
ratio = video.videoWidth / video.videoHeight;

w = video.videoWidth - 0;
h = parseInt(w / ratio, 0);
canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;

var a = "canvas.height";

}, false);


function snap(){
context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` to run a function after a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    snap();
}, 5000);
```